# Create a new table every time though a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want create a new table every time though a stored procedure.

```
declare @datetime datetime
declare @date varchar(20)

select @datetime = (GETDATE() - 1)
select @date = convert(varchar(10), @datetime, 112)

print @datetime
print @date

create table #businessmster+'_'+@date
(
    contentid int
)
```

Table name which I want is `#businessmaster_20171103`

Comment: Why would you want to dynamically name the temp table? Those are local to each proc anyway so there will be no collisions. You could create the named table with dynamic SQL but subsequent uses would need to be within the same dynamic SQL batch.

Comment: i want take a backup every day and insert in a new table.

Comment: just like.
businesmaster_20171103
businesmaster_20171104
so on

Comment: So you want a permanent table rather than a temp table (# prefix)? Update your question then.

Comment: yes and thanks bro i got the solution. thanks again

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer to your question.

Comment: one more thing bro how to insert in  this table which is created by @strTableName

Comment: To create a copy of rows from an existing table, you probably want `INSERT INTO dbo.your_backup_table (<column_list-here>) SELECT <column_list-here> FROM dbo.your_source_table`. See [insert statement documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) for syntax and example H for an `INSERT...SELECT` example.

Comment: i am using that table which is produce by below query.

Comment: insert into  @TableName
select '1' as contentid,'sandeep' as Businessname

Comment: i am using this

Comment: You can't use a variable in place of a table name in an `INSERT` statement. You'll need to construct a dynamic SQL `INSERT...SELECT` similarly to the `CREATE` table. See Erland Sommarskog's thorough [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can use this query.

```
Declare @strTableName varchar(500)
SET @strTableName = 'create table businessmster_' + @date +'( contentid int )
    GO
    INSERT INTO  businessmster_' + @date +' Select Field FROM <<YourTable>> WHERE <<Condition>>  
    GO'
Print @strTableName
Exec(@strTableName)
```

Comment: The temp table will become out of scope and dropped when the EXEC completes.

Comment: Thanks Dan for notice but here user want to take backup only using dynamic script and this will execute perfectly.

Comment: But the temp table backup will be gone after it's created. Run your script and then try to access the table to see what I mean. It seems SANDEEPRAWAT wanted a permanent table anyway so this will work in that case (no # prefix). I suggest you update your answer to remove the `#` so that it is correct.

Comment: this one is also running perfect, can you tell me how to insert the data in that table which will be produce by that query

Comment: Hello Sandeep, Please check answer agin. I have added new query for insert record into dynamic table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query as:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @TableName = N'CREATE TABLE businessmaster_'+
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate()-1,112)+
                 N' ( contentid int )';
SELECT @TableName
EXEC(@TableName);
```

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109506/create-a-new-table-every-time-though-sp/47109813#comment81169557_47109506) I remove the `#` symbol.

Comment: how can i insert the data in that table which is produce by that query